# How do I setup Google Maps API key in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to setup the Google Maps SDK for iOS development in SwiftUI and have reached step 3 in the Google Maps documentation. It now says to add the api key to "AppDelegate.swift" which is not a file I have in my project.

Doing a quick Google search shows that new Swift projects don't use that file anymore and the only way to get it is to select "Storyboard" when creating a new project. Do I need to recreate the project selecting Storyboard to be able to use the Maps SDK or is there some other place to put my api key that doesn't use the AppDelegate.swift file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be worth your time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and increase your chances of getting help from the community.